# Can't access to Samba share from Windows workstation domain

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2012, samba4

*This is a test environment - Fedora 19 updated - Windows Server 2012 with only AD and DNS*

After installing a SAMBA server on fedora 19 as a domain member - managed by a Windows Server 2012 (AD, DNS) - **I can not access shares on Windows client machines**.
On Windows 7 client I see the SAMBA server but can not access it. I don't get any prompt only an error.

By mounting the samba share on fedora machine , I can access to it and rights seem to work.

I have now spent 3 days to find a solution and I do not know if this is a problem of Samba configuration or on Windows clients

Some help would be great !

Here's how I did it:

```
yum install samba samba- winbind vim samba- winbind -client krb5-workstation krb5 -libs krb5 -auth -dialog
```

I created users and groups then I added to samba in this way :

```
pdbedit -a User1
```

The initialiation connecting to the Windows domain via kerberos is completed without problem :

```
kinit Administrateur@SILECKS.FR
klist
```

I joined the samba server to the Active Directory domain

```
net rpc join -U administrator
```

`wbinfo -u & wbinfo -g` returns me the right information

`getent passwd & getent group` also returns me the right information

**Configuration files :**

*/etc/hosts*

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain SRVFEDORA.SILECKS SRVFEDORA
```

*/etc/resolv.conf*

```
nameserver 192.168.1.200
```

*/etc/krb5.conf* has been edited accordingly

*/etc/samba/smb.conf*

```
[global]
security = ADS
realm = SILECKS.FR
workgroup = SILECKS
winbind separator = +
idmap uid = 10000-20000
idmap gid = 10000-20000
winbind enum users = yes
winbind enum groups = yes
template homedir = /home/%D/%U
template shell = /bin/bash
client use spnego = yes
winbind use default domain = yes
domain master = no
local master = no
prefered master = no
os level = 0

[homes ]
comment = Repertoire users
browseable = no
writeable = yes

[ Sharing ]
path = / share
browseable = yes
writeable = yes
printable = no
valid users = Administrator User1

[ public ]
Public comment = Repertoire
path = /public
public = yes
writeable = yes
printable = no
```

*Nsswitch configuration*

```
passwd : compat winbind
shadow: compat
group: compat winbind

# hosts: db files nisplus nis dns
hosts: files dns

bootparams : files

ethers : db files
netmasks : files
networks: files dns
protocols : db files
rpc : db files
services : db files

netgroup : files
# publickey : nisplus

automount : files
aliases : files
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution after spending a few days working on it.

Considering that this was a test environment, the firewall on the server and client windows were disabled. 
SAMBA running on Fedora19, I cut iptables but not **firewalld**. (Which I was totally unaware of the existence ...)

Under Windows, I also had to change some registry keys:

HKLM \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ Services \ LanmanWorkstation \ Parameters \ DomainCompatibilityMode = 1

HKLM \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ Services \ LanmanWorkstation \ Parameters \ DNSNameResolutionRequired = 0

HKLM \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ Services \ LanmanWorkstation \ Parameters \ RequireSecureNegociate = 0

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I am quite new to this and I was struggling with it for a few hours. But what I did to solve it was to convert my UNIX users to Samba users. That solved the problem instantly